# Converting a char array[] repersenting hex values to u64

Tags: c, casting, binary, hex

I have a char *key that represents hex values: "a35f64d2e1b5f5f" and I need to strore that in a u64 variable (64 bits). Since the char array is 16 bytes, I need to make so that the u64 variable stores each hex value into 4 bits. Therefore the whole variable will store (4 * 16) bits.

That was just an example of the values I could get, they can in fact be any 16 hex values. They specifically have to go into a u64 and I really don't know how to left shift only 4 bits at a time.

Comment: `char key[16]` can only hold 15 hex digits plus a null terminator when used as a string.

Comment: @stark If it's not treated as a null terminated string it's fine though. `char key[16] = "aa35f64d2e1b5f5f"; // one char added to make it 16 chars` is fine in C.

Comment: The [`strtoull`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoull) function ought to do the trick.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Telling `strtoull()` where the end of the string is isn't what the endptr argument does.

Comment: @Shawn Oh, misunderstanding on my part. I thought it was used both as an in and out parameter. Since that's not the case, _don't_ use `strtoull` with non null terminated strings at all :-)

Comment: strtoull works half of the time. Then it overflows into LLONG_MAX. How should I work around for those cases?

Comment: How many hex `char`s do you have in your `char[16]` array? If you have 16, you can't use `strtoull` (since it requires a null terminated string).

Comment: its a char[17] array.

Comment: @AlanAndrade "strtoull works half of the time. Then it overflows into LLONG_MAX." is suspicious.  Did you mean `ULLONG_MAX`?

Comment: Yes, ULLONG_MAX

Comment: @AlanAndrade All arrays of 16 hex-digits convert to a `unsigned long long`.  No overflow possible.

Comment: "`char *key` that represents hex values: "a35f64d2e1b5f5f" and I need to strore that in a u64 variable (64 bits). Since the char array is 16 bytes" is a contradiction.  `key` is a _pointer_, not an array.  Netiher `key` nor `"a35f64d2e1b5f5f"` are a _char array of 16 bytes_.  Best to post code that demos your problem.

Comment: @AlanAndrade "_Since the char array is 16 bytes_" and "_its a char[17] array_"  can't both be correct. Have you made sure that it's null terminated when you use `strtoull`?